# Print all subarrays in less than O(n^3) time complexity

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

To print all the subarrays (contiguous subsequences) of a given array, one requires three nested
for loops. Is there a way to reduce the time complexity of O(n^3) using map in C++ STL?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ios_base::sync_with_stdio (false);
cin.tie(NULL);
cout.tie(NULL);
vector<int> v;
int n;
cin>>n;   // the size of the array
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
int x;
cin>>x;
v.push_back(x);
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
{
for(int k=i;k<=j;k++)
cout<<v[k]<<" ";
cout<<endl;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you must iterate all elements then you must iterate all elements... No further reduction possible. Reducing time complexity is all about finding ways in which you *don't* need to iterate all elements.